# Google Charts - No data available - Unable to remove old graph and display a blank chart?

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I'm working on google charts in my angular 6 application
[npm-google-charts link](https://github.com/gmazzamuto/ng2-google-charts/blob/master/demo/src/app/app.component.ts)

Now,When I am drawing the graph based on the data from server,If I have data the graph is drawn properly but If I don't have data then I'm setting my datatable property to null but still the old graph is not erasing .

Here is my code:

In My HTML:

```
 <google-chart [data]="columnChart" (chartReady)="ready($event)"  (chartError)='error($event)'></google-chart>
```

In my TS:

```
 //chart initialization and properties
columnChart: GoogleChartInterface = {
chartType: 'ColumnChart',
// dataTable: this.data,
options: {
  height: 600,
  legend: 'none',
  hAxis: {
    direction: -1,
    slantedText: true,
    slantedTextAngle: 90,
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 11
    }
  },
   vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 20 } },
}
//Method when data is changing
changeData() {
console.log(this.data);
if(this.data.length <= 1)
{
  this.data=[];
  this.columnChart.dataTable = this.data;
  this.columnChart.component.draw();
  this.toastr.error("Unable to find food order details in selected 
month");
}
else{
  this.columnChart.dataTable = this.data;
  this.columnChart.component.draw();
}
```

Here,If the data is null I'm setting the datatable poperty to null but still the graph is showing.How to draw an empty chart if data is null

Can anyone please help me with this,
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try using the `clearChart` method...

```
if(this.data.length <= 1)
{
  this.columnChart.component.getChart().clearChart();
  this.toastr.error("Unable to find food order details in selected month");
}
else{
  this.columnChart.dataTable = this.dataToBeBinded;
  this.columnChart.component.draw();
}
```

Comment: ,Thank you for the help but clearChart method doesn't exist

Comment: my mistake, changed answer above, try --> `.getChart().clearChart()`

Comment: still the same,getChart method also doesn't exist

Comment: what class is `component` derived from? you should be using the [chart wrapper class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_4) somewhere, which does have `getChart`...